# Calculated Properties using Partial Classes(WPF)

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wpfdatagrid, partial-classes, calculated-columns

I am trying to use the calculated columns to display in my grid.

I have a partial class automatically generated by EF code generator with three properties:

Here is my code generated by EF entity generator

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Employees.Contract
{
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(Department))]
[KnownType(typeof(PropertyType))]
public partial class Employee: IObjectWithChangeTracker, INotifyPropertyChanged,IDataErrorInfo
{

    [NonSerialized]
    private CLOS.Contract.Validation.DataErrorInfoSupport dataErrorInfoSupport;

    public Employee()
    {            
        dataErrorInfoSupport = new CLOS.Contract.Validation.DataErrorInfoSupport(this);
        Init();
    }

    partial void Init();

    string IDataErrorInfo.Error { get { return dataErrorInfoSupport.Error; } }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string memberName] { get { return dataErrorInfoSupport[memberName]; } }

    #region Primitive Properties


    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<decimal> Salary
    {
        get { return _salary; }
        set
        {
            if (_salary != value)
            {
                _salary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Salary");
            }
        }
    }
    private Nullable<decimal> _salary;

    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<decimal> WageRate
    {
        get { return _wageRate; }
        set
        {
            if (_wageRate != value)
            {
                _wageRate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("WageRate");
            }
        }
    }
    private Nullable<decimal> _wageRate;

    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<decimal> Bonus
    {
        get { return _bonus; }
        set
        {
            if (_bonus != value)
            {
                _bonus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Bonus");
            }
        }
    }
    private Nullable<decimal> _bonus;

    #endregion
    #region Navigation Properties

    [DataMember]
    public Department Department
    {
        get { return _department; }
        set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_department, value))
            {
                var previousValue = _department;
                _department = value;
                OnNavigationPropertyChanged("Department");
            }
        }
    }
    private Borrower _department;

    [DataMember]
    public PropertyType PropertyType
    {
        get { return _propertyType; }
        set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_propertyType, value))
            {
                var previousValue = _propertyType;
                _propertyType = value;

                OnNavigationPropertyChanged("PropertyType");
            }
        }
    }
    private PropertyType _propertyType;

    #endregion
    #region ChangeTracking

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (ChangeTracker.State != ObjectState.Added && ChangeTracker.State != ObjectState.Deleted)
        {
            ChangeTracker.State = ObjectState.Modified;
        }
        if (_propertyChanged != null)
        {
            _propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnNavigationPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (_propertyChanged != null)
        {
            _propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged{ add { _propertyChanged += value; } remove { _propertyChanged -= value; } }
    private event PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged;
    private ObjectChangeTracker _changeTracker;

    [DataMember]
    public ObjectChangeTracker ChangeTracker
    {
        get
        {
            if (_changeTracker == null)
            {
                _changeTracker = new ObjectChangeTracker();
                _changeTracker.ObjectStateChanging += HandleObjectStateChanging;
            }
            return _changeTracker;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_changeTracker != null)
            {
                _changeTracker.ObjectStateChanging -= HandleObjectStateChanging;
            }
            _changeTracker = value;
            if(_changeTracker != null)
            {
                _changeTracker.ObjectStateChanging += HandleObjectStateChanging;
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleObjectStateChanging(object sender, ObjectStateChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewState == ObjectState.Deleted)
        {
            ClearNavigationProperties();
        }
    }

    protected bool IsDeserializing { get; private set; }

    [OnDeserializing]
    public void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        IsDeserializing = true;
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    public void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        dataErrorInfoSupport = new CLOS.Contract.Validation.DataErrorInfoSupport(this);
        IsDeserializing = false;
        ChangeTracker.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;
    }

    protected virtual void ClearNavigationProperties()
    {
        Department = null;
        PropertyType = null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

It also works if i put `OnPropertyChanged("Salary")` in Hours,Wage,Overtime Property in EF Generated class (which is not a good idea) because if the class gets regenerated , my code will be wiped out

Any help is appreciated. (Sorry for the formatting , this is my first question)

Thanks

Comment: You could try having the class handle it's own `PropertyChanged` events and use that handler to call `OnPropertyChanged("Salary")`.

Comment: Can you elaborate more my partial class(class generated by EF) already has PropertyChanged event. Any sample code will be helpful. Pardon my ignorance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue. What was happening is that service was marshaling the data back to the UI but it was not marshaling the events with the properties, so what i had to do was to call the init method from the UI and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

**Final Draft**

(I removed old edits due to irrelevance)

In your partial class add, in addition to your definition of Salary:

```
partial void Init()
{
    _propertyChanged += NotifySalary;
}

private void NotifySalary(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Wages" || e.PropertyName == "Hours" || e.PropertyName == "Overtime")
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("Salary");
    }
}
```

Comment: When i try to create the constuctor , it gives me the following error Type 'Employee' already defines a member called 'Employee' with the same parameter types

Comment: @pappu I was afraid of that. It seems EF is auto-generating a constructor. Hopefully it's an empty one. See the comments below the Edit.

Comment: From your answer it seems that i would have to modify the auto generated classes in order to achieve what i am doing which i dont want and I am using C# , Any other ideas?

Comment: Option D: Don't use EF-generated classes. In C# there's no way to link up events in the member declarations. You have to do it in a method body or in the constructor. Do you want to call another method every time you create an instance of `Employee`?

Comment: I noticed this constructor definition in EF Generated classes public Employee()
        {            
      dataErrorInfoSupport = new Validation.DataErrorInfoSupport(this);
            Init();
        }  
where Init is a Partial method and i created the same Initi Partial method.

 partial void Init()
        {

            ((INotifyPropertyChanged)this).PropertyChanged += NotifySalary;
        }.

But it does not fire Property Changed event whenever the values changes for wage hour etc.

Comment: @pappu Added another edit with an idea that will hopefully get what you're after.

Comment: It complains Error'object' does not contain a definition for 'OnPropertyChanged'

Comment: Balls. That's what I get for making assumptions. Let's back up a bit. Does the EF-generated class have any Inhetitances or Implementations?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but it is implimenting these interfaces IObjectWithChangeTracker, INotifyPropertyChanged,IDataErrorInfo

Comment: @pappu Okay, since it implements `OnPropertyChanged` changed instead of inheriting from a base class, you can't overrride it. You might try to work with the `Init` method again, as that's the only option I see left. See **New Edit 3** above.

Comment: It does not fire NotifySalary whenever there is a change. it only fires for the first time but not firing subsequently... It is Really frustrating and thanks for you help by the way. This is what i am using   partial void Init()
        {

            ((INotifyPropertyChanged)this).PropertyChanged += NotifySalary;
        }

Comment: Do you need to cast `this` to the interface? Will the line `PropertyChanged += NotifySalary` not work? The reason it's working the first time is because the bound view is making it's initial call to it. You need the Notification to fire in order to get subsequent updates.

Comment: If I dont cast it, i get the error Error 'PropertyChanged' does not exist in the current context ... and How can i force it to fire to get the subsequent updates....

Comment: @pappu I can't come up with anything else with what we have. This functionality works for me with WPF and a POCO implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, both with casting or implicitly and from separate files. The only other thing I can suggest is posting all of the EF-generated code for the class. Then I might be able to see where the hang-up is.

Comment: is it possible to email you the file?

Comment: I'd rather not leave it publicly,  can you edit the code into your question?

Comment: ok, I edited the code and put it in the question, Please see if it makes sense to you... Thanks for all your help

Comment: @pappu Got it. The INotifyPropertyChanged implementation is unusual to me. New edit should do the trick.

Comment: Check that all of the names are correct. It looks like the names provided before aren't valid anymore. The `e.PropertyName == "PropertyName"` should be the properties that you want to trigger the additional notify. The `OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName")` should be the property that you define in your partial class.

Comment: I have a debug point on NotifySalary method, and it never comes after the first time load

Comment: If you put a debug point in the EF-file's `OnPropertyChanged` method, can you see if it steps into the call to `_propertyChanged`?

Comment: Yes, it hits the following line of code in EF ' On PropertyChanged but not in the other one                                           if (_propertyChanged != null)
            {
                _propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

Comment: Can you put a break at line `if (_propertyChanged != null)` and add watch for `_propertyChanged` to see if the value is null?

Comment: It is not null and then i think it goes to this line of code ...event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged{ add { _propertyChanged += value; } remove { _propertyChanged -= value; } }

Comment: The only thing I can postulate then, is that something is being managed under the Entity Framework hood that is removing your handler that you are attaching in the `Init()` method. You might need to ask on the msdn or Entity Framework forums or create a new question. My knowledge has been exhausted.

Comment: No Problem...Thanks..I was reading somewhere that i could invoke the partial methods like "OnPropertyNameChanged" but i could not find those ...but anyways thanks for your help... I guess i need to come up with some other way to generate the calculated fields...Appreciate your help once again.